# Creating training and test set in weka using StratifiedRemoveFolds example

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

I am trying to run some classification using **weka** from the command line. In this link [weka-Primer-commandline](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer) there is the following example for creating test and training sets:

```
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i data/soybean.arff -o soybean-train.arff \
-c last -N 4 -F 1 -V

java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i data/soybean.arff -o soybean-test.arff \
-c last -N 4 -F 1
```

Is this piece of code supposed to make 3/4 of data for training and 1/4 for test set? To me seems that only one fold of the whole data(from the last because of -V) will be assigned for training and only 1 fold for test. Am I right? I need 3/4 data for training and 1/4 for test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the documentation is correct and puts 3/4 of the data in the train set and 1/4 in the test set. The options mean the following:

- `-N`: There should be 4 folds, meaning that the data is split into 4 equal non-overlapping parts
- `-F`: The first of these parts/folds should be selected
- `-V`: Inverse the selection

So the first line which creates the train set, works as follows:

- Create 4 folds
- Select the first fold and take the inverse of that which results in selecting the remaining 3 fold, which is 3/4 of the data

The test is simply created by only selecting the first fold, which is 1/4 of the data.